# 38gb of Data Used on Hard Drive with New Installation of Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive, disk-space

I just installed Windows 7 Ultimate edition on a hard drive with 74.5 GB, but as soon as I checked the computer space I found out 38 gigs were used up. Upon further investigation I found these folders to be the culprits:

Winsxs = 8gb, Installer =6gb, Software Distribution = 4gb, System32 = 2.2gb
,assembly = 1.4gb, and SysWow64 = 1.1gb, and the file pagefilesys = 4.3gb

**So How Can I recover as much space as possible from my Hard Drive?**

I already tried everything from Disk Cleanup, to vssadmin Delete Shadows /For=C: /Oldest, I also tried disabled hybernation,and limited system restore. I  dont know what else to do any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's your question besides the page file the rest is needed

Comment: Is there a way to get my hard drive to around 70 gigs by deleting all the unnecessary files?

Comment: @chosenjuan No. Windows has a lot of features and as a result, a lot of libraries and application support. Unless you know exactly what libraries and features every application you might want to install on that system needs, you can't really go deleting stuff. Even if you could, you'll not get your freespace anywhere near 70GB. Maybe in the 40-50GB range.

Comment: You can remove windows features but sounds like those feature you can remove were already removed

Comment: According to http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/products/system-requirements you need 16 GB available hard disk space (32-bit) or 20 GB (64-bit) **plus** space for your applications/data